# creating a controller same as application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, my application controller becoming bulky with definitions which are used by other controllers.Is there a way to create a controller same as application controller so the same methods can be moved into the new controller and can be accessed by other controller.like Globally define the method or something.

Comment: Please provide your application controller code. "Bulky" is a relative term.

Comment: i have many methods inside my application controller.i need to move the methods to a separate file so the controller looks neat

Comment: Please share your `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create concern for overcoming this problem

create one `CommonMethods` concern under controllers/concerns/common_methods.rb

/concerns/common_methods.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module CommonMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
   # include your filters  here like before_action
  end
  # write all common methods of application controller here
end
```

In the ApplicationController include that concern

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CommonMethods
  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: A concern for ApplicationController makes no sense to me. Concerns are for shared behavior...and ApplicationController is shared...???

Comment: @MarkMerritt  concern for not application controller, it's for common methods used by other controllers.

Comment: thank you @Vishal, i will look into this and update you if this fulfill my need

Comment: @MarkMerritt Please let me know, where else the application controller code can belong to?

Comment: @vishal..your answer includes a concern in ApplicationController...so, every controller will include those "common methods", whether they use them or not. I highly doubt there are that many common methods that need to be shared across all controllers. If there are, then they most likely belong in a lib module/class.

Comment: @Vishal this worked like a peace. this served my purpose. :)  thank you.

Comment: @Vishal but i dont this is a efficient way , as this is just a cosmetic change

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan its efficient way for thin controllers. if you need some methods only for particular controllers then divide them into different concerns and load concern controller rather than including in application controller. As per my knowledge using concern for common methods is an efficient way.